# How to redirect stdout of a child process to parent process

Tags: c++, process, parent-child, stdout

I am trying to call child processes from threads in a server application written in C++.

It first looked good, but now I am experiencing timing problems as the output of the child process gets bigger.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
int readlinesFromCommandStdout( char * const *argv, int maxLines, int timeout, std::list<std::string> &destination )
{
    int count = 0;

    int filedes[2];
    pipe( filedes );
    dup2( filedes[0], 0 );
    dup2( filedes[1], 1 );

    int flags = fcntl( filedes[0], F_GETFL, 0 );
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl( filedes[0], F_SETFL, flags );

    spawnv( P_NOWAITO, argv[0], (char * const *) argv );

    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(MAX_BUFFER);
    struct pollfd fds;
    fds.fd = filedes[0];
    fds.events = POLLRDNORM;
    int polling;

    if(!buffer)
        return -1;

    do {

        polling = poll( &fds, 1, timeout <= 0 ? 1000 : timeout );
        if ( gets( buffer ) == NULL ) {
            break;
        }
        destination.push_back( buffer );
        count++;

        if(count >= maxLines) {
            break;
        }
    } while ( polling > 0 );

    close( filedes[0] );
    close( filedes[1] );

    free(buffer);

    return count;
}
```

Sometimes that the output of two independent children gets mixed up. I am pretty sure that the fault lies in the `dup2()` calls. Are all children's `stdout` descriptors redirected to the *correct* parent thread?

Am I missing something?

Comment: The title does not make any sense. Please learn the difference between threads and processes.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: The function call is:  int count = readlinesFromCommandStdout((char *const*) argv, 1, 0, resultList);